# Magento 2: Product Detail Layout change

Tags: product, layout, page-layouts

I want to make the product detail into 2 Columns  with images at the side and description on the other side...

I want the right side containing the detail to be sticky while scrolling and left side containing the images
[image: ayou]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your requirement i suggest set your **product page layout as 1 column**, set your HTML code in left (it contains Images section) & right (product details information) container.

For **sticky right** part i suggest go with **Sticky-Kit JavaScript**, below is the source code from GitHub & working demo example from jsFiddle. Kindly check below URLs.

Source Code : [Sticky Kit GitHub source](https://github.com/leafo/sticky-kit)

Working Demo : [jsfiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/y3tdL9wd/)

Comment: Do I need to include Jquery in my Magento theme or by default It is included

Comment: You can use default theme's jQuery, but check that jQuery version it should be latest one and also include sticky-kit.js in your theme web directory.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
sticky.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at sticky.js:2
jquery.sticky-kit.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at jquery.sticky-kit.js:12
    at jquery.sticky-kit.js:251
pub/static/version1582812171/frontend/Pronko/consulting/en_US/https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Creepster:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)                                                                           facing these errors

Comment: That must be jQuery loading dependency issue, try to load jQuery library before sticky js. there maybe jQuery conflict issue you may face.

Answer (score 1):

@Nayan Baraiya,
Thanks for the reference link, i exactly want this type of sticky part in my detail page. KUDOs to you.

Comment: Thank you, let me know if you need any help.